# Javascript Function Change NCS Color

Tags: javascript, html

I've been looking around and didn't manage to resolve my case.

What I want is JS to change color based on user input value. w3schools have a library w3color.js and you simply call it by using div `data-w3-color="ncs(3010-B10R)"`

This is what I got:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
div {
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    padding-top: 30%;
    padding-right: 30%;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    padding-left: 30%;
}
</style>
<body>

<input type="text" id="myText" value="ncs code here..">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div data-w3-color="ncs(3010-B10R)">
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("myText").value;
 // change div data-w3-color to ncs code input
    }
</script>
<!--
https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_ncs.asp
-->
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3color.js"></script>
<script>w3SetColorsByAttribute();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cant make it change color to a new color I want based on user input...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given an `id` to the div and changing the `data-w3-color` attribute and calling the `w3SetColorsByAttribute()` function each time.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var color = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  // change div data-w3-color to ncs code input
  document.getElementById("ncsColor").setAttribute("data-w3-color", 'ncs('+ color +')')
  w3SetColorsByAttribute();
  
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
  padding-top: 30%;
  padding-right: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  padding-left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="ncs code here..3010-B10R">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="ncsColor" data-w3-color="ncs(3010-B10R)">
</div>

<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3color.js"></script>
```